# Restrict the user that is already connected with ftp in php

Tags: php, ftp

i am going to run a cron job every 10 sec to connect and copy files then delete. 
i do wont cron to run while it's copying files and so on, what's the best way to do this ?

Can i Restrict the user that is already connected ?

```
try {
    $con = ftp_connect($server);
    if (false === $con) {
        throw new Exception('Unable to connect');
    }

    $loggedIn = ftp_login($con,  $username,  $password);
    if (true === $loggedIn) {
        echo 'Success!';
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Unable to log in');
    }

    print_r(ftp_nlist($con, "."));
    ftp_close($con);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Failure: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if a certain file doesnt exist
    make the file
    do stuff
    delete file
else if the file exists, but its very old
    recreate the file
    do stuff
    delete file
else
    its busy
```

I wouldn't be suprised if the ftp software itself lets you restrict this. Might wanna check.